# Setting a domain name in LAN

Tags: networking, fedora, hostname

I am developing a web page using Apache Web Server in my pc. When I want to open it in the browser I use the ip, for example:

```
http://192.168.1.6/proyect
```

My host is part of a local network (a laptop and mobile device). In both of them, I can open up the website using the url mentioned above. I would like to know if it is possible to use a "domain" instead an IP in the URL? For example, `http://dev-pc/proyect`.

My first attempt was to know whether a name exists:

```
$ hostnamectl

   Static hostname: localhost.localdomain
         Icon name: computer-desktop
           Chassis: desktop
        Machine ID: d388b100e4b34a17a685369e53045669
           Boot ID: ee82c1e45d35433785b57040944928f3
  Operating System: Fedora 20 (Heisenbug)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:fedoraproject:fedora:20
            Kernel: Linux 3.19.8-100.fc20.x86_64
      Architecture: x86_64
```

Then, I test it accesing this URL:

```
http://localhost.localdomain/proyect
```

And it works, but in other devices the page is not found. Looks like `localhost.localdomain` is just recognized by my pc. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define a domain for more than just your own computer in one place, you must have some authoritative domain controller. On a home network, the thing providing the local and first-line of DNS (domain names) info is your router.

Any device on your home network is a member of the domain being defined by the router (because they are on the network, so they are a member of that network's domain). This means that your mobile devices must be using your wifi, not a cell connection.

You should be able to access your computer by its hostname.

If your dev computer does not have a hostname, define one for it with `hostname` or `hostnamectl` (depending on your flavour of unix):

```
$ sudo hostname devbox
```

or..

```
$ sudo hostnamectl set-hostname --static "devbox"
```

And now any device on the same network (inheriting that network's domain) should be able to ping your dev site by hostname:

```
$ ping devbox
64 bytes from laptop (10.1.1.13): ttl=64 time=32.9 ms
```

Comment: as you said, the key was in the router. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

What about putting a name in your /etc/hosts file (in linux) or c:\windows\system32\drives\etc\hosts file?

add a line like this:

```
192.168.1.6 dev-pc
```

Comment: What happened if the IP is dinamically set by the router every day?

Comment: For a test environment, I usually set a lot of static IPs, either in my own dhcp server or in the router, if that's what I'm using for DHCP. Unless...that is, you are testing what will happen with constantly changing IP addresses....